# example of graph such that deleting any edge couses lack of automorphism

Tags: graph-theory

Could you try give an example graph, such that deleting any edge causes lack of automorphism ?  Graph before deleting operation should have automorphism.

The only thing that I can find is examaple, but I choose edge to delete, but when it comes to deleting any edge I am helpless.
[image]

Comment: Let $G$ and $H$ be graphs, not isomorphic to each other, neither one having an automorphism. Then their union might do the trick, at any rate if one is significantly bigger than the other, so deleting an edge from one doesn't just give a copy of the other.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, this always works when $\left||E(G)|-|E(H)|\right|\geq 2$.

Comment: Note that the identity automorphishm is always a valid automorphism, so I suppose you mean lack of a non-trivial automorphism.

Comment: A graph with no edges :-)

Comment: "Note that the identity automorphishm is always a valid automorphism, so I suppose you mean lack of a non-trivial automorphism"  Yes.

Comment: I don't see an example. Has somebody an idea ?

Comment: I thought my comment contained an idea. Did you not see my comment?

Comment: I think we can take an asymmetric graph $G$ in which $G\setminus\{e\}$ is also asymmetric for every edge in $G$, then glue them in a cycle.  Rotations of this cycle will be the automorphisms of the graph, but deleting any edge will destroy these automorphisms (and not introduce any new ones).

Comment: Could you show an example ? I don't understand assymetric graph

Answer (score 2):

If you restrict yourself to graphs of minimum degree $\ge$ 1 then this is the smallest example
[image]

Comment: Degree isn't important. Where you see automorphism and why deleting edge cause deleting autopmorphism?

Comment: @bof Err I meant minimum degree $\ge$ 1